# How do I properly add jwt secret in my Jwt-Strategy?

Tags: typescript, jwt, nestjs

I just tried to start my NestJS API, but I always get this error:
"JwtStrategy requires a secret or key"
So I tried a few thing to fix this on my own.

- I tried to fill it in as a string directly
- I created a const containing the secret and filled this in
- I tried to load the key from my .env.

Thats my Strategy code so far.

```
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { ExtractJwt } from 'passport-jwt';
import { Strategy } from 'passport-jwt';


const key = 'hello';

@Injectable()
export class JwtStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ignoreExpiration: false,
      secretOrkey: process.env.JWT_SECRET,
    //secretOrKey: 'hello',
   //secretOrKey: key,
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: any) {
    return { ...payload.user };
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using `@nestjs/config` or are you using `dotenv` directly?

Comment: I am Busgin dotenv directly.

Comment: Then `process.env` should be fine to access the environment variables. Where do you have the call to `dotenv.config()`?

Comment: I just found the mistake, it has to be a capital K in `secretOrkey:` and I used a small one..
I am new here, can I "close" the question somewhere?